# How to hide segmented control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

Have `ViewController` with `SearchBar`.

[image]

After click search button appears `SearchBar` with focus

[image]

How to hide 2 segmented controls "Title"?

Comment: segmentControl.hidden=true????

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the `UISegmentedControl`, as a `UIView` subclass it has a [hidden](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property.

```
segmentedControl.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to Jeff's answer

If this code `segmentedControl.hidden = YES;` is not working.. Then Embed the segment control inside UIView and hide that view like this,

```
view.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: In header i have:
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

segmentedControl.hidden = YES;  - error

Comment: Lol, guys, i caught him :D

Its not segmented controls, look screenshot, my red segments on the background. Its scope titles :D

Answer (score 0):

I am adding Swift 3 solution so that it will be useful for others. In Swift 3, you can hide `UISegmentedControl` like this

`segmentedControl.isHidden = true`